# convert small matrices into larger matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

In my previous question, I ask about divide a matrix into small matrices :

```
<1*50 double>%array = <1*25 double> <1*25 double>%cell
```

And i have got the answer:

```
for i=1:n %division in n array 
  A{i}=A(FLOOR((end/n)*(i-1)+1):ceil((end/n)*i))
end
```

Now the question is how to convert that small matrices into the bigger one?

```
<1*25 double> <1*25 double>%cell = <1*50 double>%array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the small matrices all have appropriate sizes, you can just use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html?refresh=true):

```
cell2mat(A)
```